# how split data in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ddf()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
Do Until Range("a1").Value = ""
x = InStr(1, Range("a1"), ".")
y = InStr(1, Range("a1"), "?")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If x > y Then
Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Left(Range("a1"), y)
Range("a1") = Replace(Range("a1"), Range("a" & lr + 1), "")
ElseIf x = 0 Then
Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Left(Range("a1"), y)
Range("a1") = Replace(Range("a1"), Range("a" & lr + 1), "")
ElseIf y = 0 Then
Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Left(Range("a1"), x - 1)
Range("a1") = Replace(Range("a1"), Left(Range("a1"), x), "")
Else
Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Left(Range("a1"), x - 1)
Range("a1") = Replace(Range("a1"), Left(Range("a1"), x), "")
End If
Loop
Exit Sub
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

In above code i want to loop the steps till range("a1")  become blank. Please tell me where need corrections in above code.

Comment: I did corrections in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place

```
x = InStr(1, Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1"), ".")
y = InStr(1, Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1"), "?")
```

Also right before

```
Loop
```

And place both just after the last

> End If

Comment: That is just for having a proper "Do Until-Loop" functioning  and nested "If-Then-Else". But as to your very goal you may want to give more details to let us help you more effectively

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Actually, i have data in A1 and i want to split the data into last row in column where i got (.) or (?) mark in the data.

Comment: This way you can align your offer to their needs and increase brand loyalty. According to a study by Cint, 62% of consumers are more likely to buy from a brand that has asked for their opinion (source)?
Worried about negative consumer backlash? Collecting criticism shows you what needs to be changed but feedback form is also a great outlet for you users. You’d rather see negative opinions in your feedback inbox than all over social media, right? "This is data in A1"

Comment: In results, i don't want (.) in data but i want (?) in data. i.e., In a2 cell "This way you can align your offer to their needs and increase brand loyalty" in a3 cell "According to a study by Cint, 62% of consumers are more likely to buy from a brand that has asked for their opinion (source)?" in a3 cell "Worried about negative consumer backlash?" in a4 cell "Collecting criticism shows you what needs to be changed but feedback form is also a great outlet for you users" in a5 cell "You’d rather see negative opinions in your feedback inbox than all over social media, right?"

Comment: in results the cell should be trimmed values (i don't want unwanted spaces at begin and end of line)

Comment: If my "corrections" actually made your code go, you would accept my answer. If you found it useful you may want to up-vote it also. As for the new request you'd better start a new question where to place updated code and specify what it does that shouldn't and what it does not that should